# How to overcome the css problems in IE

Tags: sapui5

I have developed a application, which i tried to run to run in different browsers.
In Google Chrome its working properly.

But when i run the same application in Internet Explorer some CSS are not affecting properly.
The thing i noticed in the debugger is the application is loading the library.css file from resources,
means from the below path its taking that css file and it is affecting my application.

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/themes/sap_bluecrystal/library.css

Where as in Chrome its not loading any such library.css file.

How can i over come this..?

Please help me on this.

Thanks
Sathish.

Comment: first, can you tell me the version of IE you are talking about? Is it possible to give me url to your application to access and explore it myself. In general there should not be difference of the loaded files on different browsers. Regards,
Ilhan

Comment: Did you apply any additional CSS yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Don't load css file in index.html,because in server index.html will not load,so the final solution is we need to load external css file in component.This is the best practise.

Answer (score 0):

**"Use browser prefix so that it will work in IE"**

Some reference links [MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

[some unknown but useful](https://www.thoughtco.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867)